# Multisided input for single crafting recipe with Applied Energistics

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-applied-energistics, minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack

I'm trying to figure out of the Applied Energistics mod, but I've met a bit of a snag. To create Enriched Alloy I need to use the Metallurgic Infuser. The problem is that it needs two inputs, redstone and iron, and they can't both be inserted on the same side, and the ME Interface is of course only connected to one side.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The interface only exports and then the AE system waits until the result gets put into the network *somehow*. There is no need to put the interface on the actual machine.

This means you can let the interface export to a buffer inventory and then let another item transport system put everything in the correct side.

The pure AE way would be a subnet, the interface with the pattern is connected to the main system and wrenched to point to another interface connected to the second (independent) network which uses export buses to put everything in the correct place, then the main network can import the result.

Answer (score -1):

You could have an export bus just fill up the infuser, and have the interface only insert iron to craft an infused alloy. Using Compressed Redstone makes this fairly efficient. This would also mean you have to set aside an infuser for just alloy.